# pkg OSVERSION mismatches jail/host

Tags: freebsd

I have a FreeBSD Host and some jails, the output of `freebsd-version -u` in the host and in the jail is `12.2-STABLE`.

In the host the output of `uname -K` and `pkg -vv | grep OSVERSION` matches  `1202505` but within the jail I get `OSVERSION = 1201512;`

I updated the host and the jail but still not finding why the mismasth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `usr/src/obj` directory and rebuild because this file:

```
usr/src/amd64.amd64/host-osreldate.h
```

was not getting updated when using `-DNO_CLEAN`:

```
env MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX=/jroot/build/obj SRCCONF=/etc/src-jail.conf __MAKE_CONF=/etc/make.conf make -DNO_CLEAN -j${NUMBER_OF_CORES} buildworld
```

Using [devel/ccache](https://www.freshports.org/devel/ccache) helps fixing the problem, just need to add `WITH_CCACHE_BUILD=yes` in `src.conf`

From the man:

```
 WITH_CCACHE_BUILD
             Set to use ccache(1) for the build.  No configuration is required
             except to install the devel/ccache package.
```